# Gif Crashing on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, gif

Gif was running smoothly on the simulator, but crashing in the device due to the memory. How to handle this. I have googled a lot but didn't find any kind of the solution to it.

The following is the code which I am using to load the Gif

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[utility getString] withExtension:@"gif"]; 
self.img.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you load it in a webview ? or you have a series of uiimages that are loaded in an imageview ?

Comment: I use this library for gif and it works very well. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @gottlieb The following is the code which I am using to load the Gif

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[utility getString] withExtension:@"gif"];
    
  
    self.img.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge It crashes due to memory pressure and high increase in memory usage.

check these links it may helps you [link1](http://vikrambahl.com/animated-gifs-ios-xcode-storyboards/) , [link2!!](https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone)and [link3!!](https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

Use FLAnimatedImage Library from Github :- Use [https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/) It is easy to use and memory friendly.

## import "FLAnimatedImage.h"

## import "FLAnimatedImageView.h"

```
FLAnimatedImage *image         = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"]]];
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animatedImage        = image;
imageView.frame                = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0); //As your Wish you can set frame
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

It's a well-tested component.